# Logging in at Ask Question page discards question

Tags: bug, status-completed, editing, asking-questions

I painstakingly wrote a question up, not realizing I wasn't logged in.  When I was done, I noticed that there was a log-in button below the question box, so I assumed that's what I needed to do to proceed with posting my question.

After I logged in, I was taken back to the home screen, not my post.  When I used my browser's back button to go back to my question, everything I had typed was gone.  This is extremely frustrating.  If you log in from the Ask Question page using the inline log-in button, it should save the state of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty edge case. Usually if you start a draft, it gets saved, so that if you leave the page it's still there when you come back. I believe drafts only get saved if you're logged in though, so in this case... not logged in, no draft gets saved when you leave to log in. Unfortunately, I don't think there's much we can do to recover it at this point.

Comment: Anonymous users also have drafts saved.  As for not saving the edtior's text during a log in action, this would definitely be a bug.  Looking into it.

Comment: Looks like we were just dropping the final redirect, this will be fixed in the next deploy.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!